# I'm writing an app for developers - should I use "proper" MiB, or just MB?

Tags: gui-design, ios

In short, the app I'm writing is a tool for accessing data stored in databases and backend systems.  Part of this is displaying the size of any files stored there.

Given this will (predominantly) be used by other developers, should I be displaying the proper size values in mebibytes or go with what is often the assumed definition in megabytes?

I.e. I have 3 options:

1) Go for "true" megabytes - 1000 KB = 1MB (given MB is a better recognised unit than MiB)

2) Go for "false" megabytes - 1024KB = 1MB (given this is what is widely assumed to be 1 MB)

3) Go for mebibytes - 1024 KiB = 1MiB (given this is the most accurate of the 3).

I'm in two minds, as while most experienced developers go for the correct definitions - newer developers (those perhaps more likely to use a 3rd party tool) are more unlikely to.

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

P.s. Were this an app for everyday users, which option would you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Go with option 1

Rationale: You're clearly stating that this app will be *predominantly* used by developers, which means not all users will be developers. Even if so, you may find experienced developers, medium level developers and new people. So, there's a chance some people won't know your acronym, hence causing friction. As an example: I have a quite extensive experience in coding and I'm not ashamed to admit that while I knew the acronym, I didn't knew exactly what did it represent.

Now, think about this: Option 2 is not accurate. Then, why use it? Either you use accurate definitions or you use nothing. Option 3 is not known by everybody for the reasons above.

So, what you have to ask yourself is this: what benefits do you get from different options? personally I can't see any benefits on options 2 and 3, but you'll need to analyze this yourself

Comment: The benefit of Option 2 is familiarity. Windows OS, the most commonly used desktop OS uses Option 2. Until I started using a Mac I didnt know about Option 1 and until Junior year as a CS major didn't know about Option 3. Edit - not saying I disagree with your choice of option 1, just noting there is atleast some reason for option 2

Comment: That's why I said *personally* and that he should analyze it since I understand for some people it might be different

Comment: +1 While many developers are sticklers for details, the MB numbers are by now widely recognized to be ambiguous. Unless we are trying to fit something into a limited space, even we developers don't much care anymore. Caveat being that of course I am only a sample of one.

Answer (score 3):

Why force the decision on the user? In your onboarding/setup, why not ask the user which format they prefer, and let them switch in settings?

Comment: Mmm good point - while I think I'll set option 1 as default, I might offer an option to change it

Comment: Why not ask? Because asking is putting the burden on the user. See all the relevant books on why sensible defaults need to be in place and why you shouldn't ask users for decisions on matters they don't understand and/or don't care about. If you do want to make this customizable, don't ask in the onboarding, but do give an option to change it somewhere in the settings. You will still have to pick a sensible default though.